# What do the Neutral Jungle Creep Buffs do in SMITE?

Tags: smite

Smite beta just opened up this week and I've already managed to get a few games in. Along the mini-map I noticed several icons that are for neutral creep camps with buffs and I was wondering what each buffs did for the player or team.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since an update in 2013 the jungle camps changed (again).

Currently, the following buffs are in place:

- **Damage**: +20% magical and physical power, +10 magical power, +5 physical power (increasing your damage), icon: red sword
- **Mana**: +5 Mana/s, 10% cooldown reduction, icon: blue bottle/jar
- **Speed**: +20% movement speed, 10% attack speed, icon: yellow double-arrow
- **None**: monsters merely giving XP and gold, icon: yellow dot
- **Gold fury**: 300 gold, 200 experience to each teammember, icon: big yellow dot
- **Fire giant**: +4%hp/5s, 2%mp/5s, +70 magical power, +50 physical power, +15% damage on towers and phoenixes, icon: fire

Previous to the current buffs, since an update in December 2012 the jungle camps provided different bonuses:

- **Cooldown**: 20% cooldown reduction, white icon with time-circle and arrow)
- **Damage**: +20% magical and physical power (increasing your damage), icon: red sword
- **Mana**: +7 Mana/s, icon: blue bottle/jar
- **Speed**: +20% movement speed, icon: yellow double-arrow
- **None**: monsters merely giving XP and gold, icon: yellow dot
- **Gold fury**: 300 gold to each teammember, icon: big yellow dot
- **Fire giant**: +30 mp5, +30 hp5, +100 magical power, +70 physical power, icon: fire

The normal buffs have a duration of 2 minutes, and the monsters respawn after 4 minutes. Firegiant has a duration of 4 minutes.

Before the December 2012 patch there were two additional buffs: Protection (+50 mag + phys protection) and Health (+10 Health/s). Additionally, the non-buff jungle monsters did not exist yet.

Reference:

- [Buffs article on SmiteWiki](http://www.smitewiki.com/Buffs)
- [Buffs article before december 2012 patch on SmiteWiki](http://www.smitewiki.com/index.php?title=Buffs&oldid=5579)

Answer (score 4):

Each camp has one buff type

- Blue- mana regen
- Orange - run speed
- Red - damage boost
- Yellow - damage resist
- White - cooldown reduction
- Green - health regen

There are also 2 large NPCs,  one for extra gold and one for large team buff